# How to tell robotframework to generate the log.html with a big size?

Tags: robotframework

We are using robotframework 2.9. And some test cases are quite big that a log.html should be generated about 20Mb. It never succeeds.

I wonder if there are ways to tell pybot to make the bigger log.html size?

Thank you very much.

PS.

The last several lines of output.xml are as following:

```
<errors>
<msg timestamp="20160517 15:12:21.007" level="WARN">Token validation > failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 15:12:22.316" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 15:12:24.665" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 15:12:25.860" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 15:18:01.213" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 15:18:02.386" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 15:18:04.671" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 15:18:05.869" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 15:28:39.428" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 15:28:40.625" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 15:28:42.940" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 15:28:44.115" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 17:06:53.696" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 17:06:54.892" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 17:06:57.213" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160517 17:06:58.416" level="WARN">Token validation failed. Retrying request with html hidden items.</msg>
</errors>
</robot>
```

Comment: What happens when "it never succeeds"? Does the process never finish? Does it crash? Does it generate a bad report? I just now processed a 47mb output.xml into a 13mb log.html and it worked fine. It took about two minutes, but it generated a valid log file.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley in fact the test case passed and an output.xml is ok. However, the log.html is never made.

Comment: So, no errors are displayed when it tries to generate the log? Are yo certain you aren't using a command line option that turns that feature off? I'd expect that if it fails, you'd get some sort of error.

Comment: Quite sure. I checked oytput.xml There are not errors. Any other way to check that? My robot framework is 2.8.5. Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. The title says "it never succeeds" which implies that it tries and fails, but it sounds  like it's no teven trying to generate the log since you say you don't get any errors. What do the last six lines of output look like?

Comment: @BryanOakley it never succeeded generating log.html. I will find out a sample and show you.

Comment: What does "_never succeeded_" mean? Are you saying that the commands to generate it run, and they complete without any error messages or any output at all?

Comment: @BryanOakley the test case run ok, every command in the test script has been run. In the very *last* phase pybot cannot make out a log.html even if the output.xml is quite ok telling us the case passed.

Comment: @BryanOakley I converted output.xml into log.html with rebot tool. the output.xml was about 49M and the log.html was about 12M. The thing I wondered is why log.html was not converted at runtime in the end of the test case running.

Comment: What are the last few lines of output _on the console_? The part that normally shows that it generated a log and report file? Show the exact command line you're using to run the tests. Are you running the tests from the command line, or from some other tool?

Comment: @BryanOakley perhaps the cpu load is too high to make the log.html.

Comment: If that were true, pybot would throw an error. You keep implying that it does not throw an error.

Comment: @BryanOakley in fact i didn't observe the console prints. It ran at night and triggered by a ci system.

Comment: Your first step is to look at that output. If there's an error generating the report, that's where it  will be.

Comment: @BryanOakley i don't know pybot throws exception if cpu load is high, it is a good direction for me to track it. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113335/discussion-between-stefanzweig-and-bryan-oakley).